# How we can get Sharepoint 2016 InfoPath Forms Services in Central admin?

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, 2016, central-administration

In SharePoint 2016 central admin infopath form services option missing.
How we can get this option in Central admin ?

Answer (score 1):

In central admin this service is under General Application settings.

- On the Quick Launch of the Central Administration Web site, click
  General Application Settings.
- On the General Application Settings page, in the InfoPath Forms
  Services section, click Configure InfoPath Form Services.

You should be using the SharePoint Server enterprise edition.

Comment: under General Application settings infothpath feature is not present.
I tried with this powershell script also.
Install-SPFeature -path "IPFSWebFeatures" -force
Install-SPFeature -path "IPFSSiteFeatures" -force

Comment: That's mean u are on standard edition of SharePoint, this feature only available in enterprise edition.

Comment: HI waqas we are having standard edition of SharePoint.In infopath we are getting this error (Warning
The amount of data that was returned by a data connection has exceeded the maximum limit that was configured by the server ).

Comment: In enterprise edition if we are change the limit of the Data Connection Response Size this error wil go. But standard edition  how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

on central admin>more features>infopath